# Enviar la informacion de un select a una pagina php por ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Necesito enviar la información del select por medio de ajax a una pagina php, el select lo utilizo como buscador gracias a select2

```
            <label>Marca</label>
            <select name="Marca_Vehiculo" id='buscadorMarca' style='width: 250px; '>
                <option  value='0'>Marca</option>
            </select>
```

El script para el select es el siguiente:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $("#buscadorMarca").select2({
                ajax: {
                    url: "buscarMarca.php",
                    type: "post",
                    dataType: 'json',
                    delay: 250,
                    data: function (params) {
                        return {
                            palabraClave: params.term, // search term
                        };
                    },
                    processResults: function(response) {
                        return {
                            results: response
                        };
                    },
                    cache: true
                }
                
            });

        });
```

Y quisiera mandar lo que aparece en el select a una pagina que denominé como buscarLinea.php

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 1):

Sí lo que buscas es pasar el dato seleccionado a otro archivo podrías hacer lo siguiente con JQuery.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es-Mx">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="js/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <style href="css/general.css"></style>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#select").change(function(){
                var select = $('#select').val();
                $.ajax({
                    url:'buscarLinea.php',
                    type:'POST',
                    data: {select:select},
                    success: function(data) {
                        $("#ejemplo").html(data);  
                    },
                 });
            });
        }); 
</script>
    <title>Ejemplo paso de parametro</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container" style="min-height:500px;">    
        <div class="row p-4">
            <h2>Ejemplo paso de parametro</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3 p-4">
            <form class="" method="post" id="codeForm">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label">Select : </label>
                    <select name="select" id="select" class="form-control">
                        <option selected="selected" disabled="disabled">Selecciona una opción</option>
                        <option value="Dato uno">Dato uno</option>
                        <option value="Dato 2">Dato 2</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-9">
            <div class="ejemplo"></div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Ahora tu php quedaría así

```html
$variable = $_POST['select'];

 echo $variable;
```

y en el contenedor con id "ejemplo" se mostraría lo siguiente:

sí seleccionas la opción uno opción 1:

"Dato uno"

sí seleccionas la opción uno opción 2:

"Dato 2"

Comment: que pena por mi ignorancia pero a que te refieres en la parte que dice; "Aquí pondrías el identificador de tu etiqueta donde quieres mostrar tu resultado(#ejemplo)"

Comment: No te preocupes, me refiero a que si en tu front tuvieras un contenedor (div) donde quisieras que se mostrara el resultado de paso de parámetros, tendría que colocar el id de ese contenedor en ese apartado que te comente.

Comment: Revisa nuevamente, acabo de ponerte el ejemplo de una forma más estructurada para que lo puedas visualizar mejor.

Answer (score 0):

Intuyo que lo que necesitas, es que cuando tu elijas un campo del select, este se pase al archivo php, y que por ejemplo ¿haga un filtro con este? En tal caso deberías de utilizar algo así:

```
<form action=""> 
<select onchange="llamadaPHP(this.value)">
    <option>Anna</option>
    <option>Amanda</option>
    <option>Eva</option>
    <option>Eve</option>
</select>
</form>

<p>Respuesta del php: <span id="respuesta"></span></p> 

<script>
function llamadaPHP(str) {
  var xhttp;
  if (str.length == 0) { 
    document.getElementById("respuesta").innerHTML = "";
    return;
  }
  xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("respuesta").innerHTML = this.responseText;
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "gethint.php?q="+str, true);
  xhttp.send();   
}
</script>
```

En este caso, el nombre de tu archivo de php es `gethint.php`, y el nombre de la variable que le estás pasando se llama q.

Con esto, ya le estarías pasando información al php, pero si quieres que te devuelva algo, deberás de tener algo parecido en tu PHP:

```
// Por ejemplo un array con nombres
$a[] = "Anna";
$a[] = "Brittany";
$a[] = "Cinderella";
$a[] = "Diana";
$a[] = "Eva";
$a[] = "Fiona";
$a[] = "Gunda";
$a[] = "Hege";
$a[] = "Inga";
$a[] = "Johanna";
$a[] = "Kitty";
$a[] = "Linda";
$a[] = "Nina";
$a[] = "Ophelia";
$a[] = "Petunia";
$a[] = "Amanda";
$a[] = "Raquel";
$a[] = "Cindy";
$a[] = "Doris";
$a[] = "Eve";
$a[] = "Evita";
$a[] = "Sunniva";
$a[] = "Tove";
$a[] = "Unni";
$a[] = "Violet";
$a[] = "Liza";
$a[] = "Elizabeth";
$a[] = "Ellen";
$a[] = "Wenche";
$a[] = "Vicky";

// recogemos el valor pasado por el select
$q = $_REQUEST["q"];

$hint = "";

// compara con todos los valores en caso de que lo que le pases sea diferente a ""
if ($q !== "") {
    $q = strtolower($q);
    $len=strlen($q);
    foreach($a as $name) {
        if (stristr($q, substr($name, 0, $len))) {
            if ($hint === "") {
                $hint = $name;
            } else {
                $hint .= ", $name";
            }
        }
    }
}

// Devuelve "sin sugerencias" en caso de que ninguno coincida
echo $hint === "" ? "sin sugerencias" : $hint;
```